# Does Paypal Express not dispatch checkout_submit_all_after event? If so how can I make it do it?

Tags: checkout, event-observer, paypal-express

I have several modules that rely on the `checkout_submit_all_after` event and when users checkout using Paypal express it seems none of their observers run. How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: yes Paypal Express does NOT fire `checkout_submit_all_after`. we need to modify file Mage/Paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php  by rewrite to fire this same event.

Answer (score 6):

It seems Paypal Express does NOT fire checkout_submit_all_after. I ended up moving everything over to observe the sales_order_place_after event instead.

Answer (score 1):

`checkout_submit_all_after`

Is fired by the checkout/type/* models.... at the time the order is finally saved to the database during checkout.

The paypal module has an event hook on this. But if your orders are being placed and saved and show up in the admin, then this even is firing from Onepage or Multishipping type models.

Google triggers this event (if you're using Magento with google checkout) when google posts back to your site in `Mage_GoogleCheckout_Model_Api_Xml_Callback`

If an order is placed via api it fires in `\Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart_Api::createOrder`

Please post your `config.xml` that is hooking onto the event, most likely you have a syntax issue there.

Comment: in case of papal checkout type is different. it is `paypal/express_checkout` `Mage/Paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php`  so it does not fire this event.

Comment: Yes, it does...

Comment: in which version ?

Answer (score 0):

**we can use here**

```
paypal_express_place_order_success
```

it will work like

```
checkout_submit_all_after
```

Comment: Mind that this event is only available in Magento 2, not in Magento 1.

Comment: Thank you @Simon,

I don`t have good knowledge of Magento 1